# In which module did Goblins terrorize villagers with a Giant Mechanical Turtle?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, published-adventures, product-identification

A while ago I stumbled upon a low-level adventure in which a band of goblins has a giant mechanical turtle and terrorizes/scares the locals with it. I think it must have been a D&D/Pathfinder 3.X book, but my google-Fu is too weak to find it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Philipp, I edited your question a bit to fit our format better. Don't forget to read our [FAQ].

Comment: I was hoping someone was able to answer this, but I suppose the supplement just does not exist :(

Comment: I fear my memory has cheated me. I knew the issue of Dragon that @Discord pointed at, so I accepted his answer, though in mind there was a grand module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to recall a similar adventure in Dungeon Magazine, where the goblin were using the shell of a Dragon Turtle to cause trouble. I believe this would have been from around the time Paizo Publishing took over the magazine, so it could be late 3.0/early 3.5.

Comment: I just had a look at Dungeon 96 which contains a very short adventure with orcs an a dragon turtle shell. It's not the one I have faint memories of, but maybe it's a good starting point for something homebrewn.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible that you are remembering *Goblins' Return* and *Heart of the Enemy*, SJS1 and SJQ1, respectively, from Spelljammer. I can't be certain, as I only recall these modules on the shelf of the FLGS I managed in the late 80s (1987-89,1990).

In Spelljammer, the DragonTurtle Ship, or Turtle Ship, is a "gammraoid" that fits the description. The two adventures, for 7th-11th level characters (not quite "low level" but not paragon or epic either), explore goblinkin's return from a banishment (after the Unhuman War).

I cannot think of another tie-in, *à la Earthshaker!* for D&D (module CM4, BECMI), where a mechanical foe of anthropomorphic design is run by Goblins.